# Mapping Xamarin (Android) touch event coords to webview pixels

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a webview in an android xamarin application. When a user swipes the screen left or right I need to check if the swipe happened over a specific element. To handle the swipe logic I am using this code:

```
float startY = 0;
private void BindTouchEvents() {
    float startX = 0;
    float webViewWidth = 0;

    webView.Touch += (sender, e) => {
        if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            webViewWidth = webView.Width;

            startX = e.Event.GetX();
            startY = e.Event.RawY; //I've tried both GetY and RawY here
        }
        if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            float movement = e.Event.GetX() - startX;
            float offset = webViewWidth / 2;

            if (Math.Abs(movement) > offset)
            {
                if (movement < 0)
                {

                    client.NotifyTouch(webView, e.Event.GetX(), startY, "SwipeLeft");
                }
                else
                {
                    client.NotifyTouch(webView, e.Event.GetX(), startY, "SwipeRight");

                }
            }
        }
        e.Handled = false;
    };
}
```

The client.NotifyTouch call invokes some javascript in the webview which determines if the swipe event occured over a specific element. If it did, it toggles that elements visibility to hidden. The element is in a fixed position at 0,0 and is 64px in height, so this logic is quite simple:

```
$scope.$on('received-touch-event', function (e, args) {     
    if ($scope.showLaunchNavBar && (args.event === "SwipeLeft" || args.event === "SwipeRight") && args.y > 0 && args.y < 64) {
        $scope.showLaunchNav(false);
    };          
});
```

The problem is that the startY value doesn't seem to translate evenly to webview pixels. For example, if I try to swipe roughly at 0,0 and inspect the starting Y position it's above 100, if I try to swipe roughly at 0,64, the starting Y position ends up being above 400. I need to figure how to translate these values into WebView pixels. I'm assuming it has something to do with the pixel density on my device, but I'm not sure how to go about translating the values into "web-pixels" in a generic way that would work across all devices.

I've tried googling, reading docs and searching on here for an answer but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Probably not using right terminology. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out, here's the solution:

```
public static float ConvertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context)
{
    return dp / ((float)context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi / (float)DisplayMetricsDensity.Default);
}
```

Comment: please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.